# Does an integral preserve strict inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, continuity, integral-inequality

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are real valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $f(t)<g(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Is it true that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(t) \ dt<\int_{0}^{1}g(t) \ dt \ ?$$ I know that this result is true when we replace "$<$" by "$\leq$".

Comment: Even if $f(t)\le g(t)$ for all $t$ and $f(t)<g(t)$ for at least one point in $[0,1]$ then also $\int_{0}^{1}f(t) \ dt<\int_{0}^{1}g(t) \ dt $ holds.

Comment: I assume this is only true when $f$ and $g$ are continuous (as in my case)? Since continuity implies strict inequality in a neighbourhood of the point where strict inequality holds.

Comment: At the point of strict inequality, continuity is  sufficient.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question, I have seen much worse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, of course, because the integral of a positive continuous function is positive:
$$\int_0^1g(x)dx-\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1(g(x)-f(x))dx>0.$$

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I realized that and deleted my comment :)

Comment: Of course. I can't believe I didn't think of this elementary argument... Thank you!

Comment: @Jens You are welcome!

Comment: ok, but then how do you prove that the integral of a positive function is positive? if it is say piecewise continuous it's not too hard, otherwise (if we are working with Lebesgue integral) some argument might be welcome

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki In the general it's just wrong. See please better the given. Our functions are continuous.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg ok, maybe I'm having a brainfart, but do you have an example of a (measurable) strictly positive function on $[0,1]$ with integral zero? (also thank you for pointing out the functions are assumed to be continuous)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg [It does hold in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855015/631742)

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I meant that in the general $f-g$ can be not integrable.

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch Thank you, but I knew this fact. See please my previous comment. I think it's also interesting.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ah, ok I see; I just misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 1):

lets suppose that:
$$f(t)<g(t)\Rightarrow f(t)-g(t)<0$$
intuitively this would give:
$$\int_0^1\left[f(t)-g(t)\right]dt<0$$
which is the same as:
$$\int_0^1f(t)dt<\int_0^1g(t)dt$$
since integrals follow the property:
$$\int\left[\alpha(x)+\beta(x)\right]dx=\int\alpha(x)dx+\int\beta(x)dx$$