# Why can the equal sign $(=)$ be included in the below inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of random variables defined on a given fixed probability space $\left(\Omega\text{, }\mathcal{F}\text{, }\mathbb{P}\right)$.
Consider that $\mathbb{P}\left(\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\right)=\mathbb{E}\{1_{\{\vert X_n-X\vert >\varepsilon\}}\}$. Then, consider the event $\{\omega:\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\}$. One is allowed to state that $$\{\omega:\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\}\Leftrightarrow\Bigg\{\omega:\frac{\vert X_n-X\vert^p}{\varepsilon^p}>1\Bigg\}$$
Henceforth $\dfrac{\vert X_n-X\vert^p}{\varepsilon^p}>1$ on the event $\{\omega:\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\}= \{\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\}$. So, I think I could state that the below inequality holds true
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\right)=\mathbb{E}\{1_{\{\vert X_n-X\vert >\varepsilon\}}\}<\mathbb{E}\Bigg\{\frac{\vert X_n-X\vert^p}{\varepsilon^p}1_{\{\vert X_n-X\vert >\varepsilon\}}\Bigg\}$$
However, on my book I read 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\vert X_n-X\vert>\varepsilon\right)=\mathbb{E}\{1_{\{\vert X_n-X\vert >\varepsilon\}}\}\leq\mathbb{E}\Bigg\{\frac{\vert X_n-X\vert^p}{\varepsilon^p}1_{\{\vert X_n-X\vert >\varepsilon\}}\Bigg\}$$
So, my **question** is: *why is equal sign $(=)$ included in the inequality on my book?* I cannot figure out why one could be allowed to include it, given the above reasoning.

Comment: If $a < b$ then $a \le b$ so the book only looses a tiny bit of information. Also there seem to be cases where $<$ doesn't hold. What if $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$ has measure 0

Comment: Yeah, but in the end this turns out to be essential, since the conclusion is that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\right)\leq0$ which implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\right)=0$. If instead one ends up with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\right)<0$, this is clearly not possible since probability is non-negative. So, I think it makes a big difference, doesn'it? @Gribouillis

Comment: When you take a limit, you will lose the strict inequality, it will have to become non-strict. e.g. $-1/n < 0$. Then take limit, you have to conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1/n) \leq 0$

Comment: If you take a limit a strict inequality becomes large. No the question here is does a strictly positive function have a positive integral. This is not true on a set of measure $0$

Comment: I understand your explanation "When you take a limit, you will lose the strict inequality" intuitively, especially thanks to your example. However, could I find some rigorous result telling me so? Some reference? @T_M

Comment: As pointed out in the other answer, it seems like the limit was not your real issue. The issue is that actually you really need the non-strict inequality to be correct. If $f$ is integrable and $f > 1$ on the set $S$ then $\int f \mathbf{1}_S d\mu \geq \mu(S)$. I cannot put $>$ because we might have $\mu(S) = 0$, in which case both sides are zero.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again @T_M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be when does the expectation preserve strict inequality. Here is a sufficient condition: [When does the integral preserve strict inequalities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855008/when-does-the-integral-preserve-strict-inequalities)
This might be useful for future reference.

As you can see, this condition is not satisfied here. One of the possible problems is that $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| > \epsilon) = 0$$ is possible (for example, when $X_n = X$ a.s.) and then both sides are $0$, so we have equality. Thus strict inequality cannot hold in general

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised how often I had this question when teaching analysis.

The notation $x < y$ means ''*$x$ is less than $y$*''.

The notation $x \leq y$ means ''$x$ is less than or equal to $y$'',

i.e. $x$ is less than $y$ or $x$ is equal to $y$.

Comment: Yes, of course, I know this. The doubt arose since the conclusion on the book is that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n−X|>\varepsilon)\leq0$ which implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n−X|>\varepsilon)=0$. If instead one ends up with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n−X|>\varepsilon)<0$, this is clearly not possible since probability is non-negative. However, above I have been told by other users that when taking limits, strict inequality 'gets larger'

Comment: OK sure. But you didn't ask about the limit in the question, you asked why one is allowed to include a non strict inequality.

Comment: Answer you're looking for has been provided.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right, sorry. And thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

The strict inequality doesn't hold when $\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X|>\varepsilon) = 0$ because the integral of a strictly positive function on a set of measure $0$ is $0$.